# Seagate 1tb external hard drive not working

Tags: usb-drive

I was watching a video from the drive and moving some files from one folder to another when vlc crashed and my desktop stopped responding (to mouse clicks etc)  I turned the laptop off using the power button and when rebooted the drive doesn't show up. Weird, and annoying as I just bought the drive recently. Help anyone?

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l
```

Output:

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL   SIZE FSTYPE
sda                     465.8G 
├─sda1 /boot/efi          512M vfat
├─sda2 /                461.4G ext4
└─sda3 [SWAP]             3.9G swap
sr0                      1024M 
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   496GB  495GB   ext4
 3      496GB   500GB  4182MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

and

```
lsblk
```

Output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 461.4G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Will you edit your question and put the output of `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l` in it?

Comment: Done, see above, thanks. Looks like not showing up right.

Comment: When you disconnect the drive and connect it again, any changes ? Do you see anything in dmesg then ?

Comment: No, nothing happens.

Comment: Try a different port.  While it's unlikely that you are using a cable, try a different cable if you are.  Also, to eliminate the possibility of it being an issue with your installation, see if it's recognized when you boot to a live session and plug it in.

Comment: Live session? Doesn't work in any port, whether plugged in after boot up or before. Tried with alternative cable, no dice. As I said, it happened while in use so I'm really confused. In the past problems came from dropping drives etc... Arghh.

Comment: Does `gparted` find the drive? How about `testdisk`?

Comment: gparted doesn't see it. Will try test disk now...

Comment: nothing with  testdisk ...

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l
```

Output -

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT                  LABEL   SIZE FSTYPE
sda                                      465.8G 
├─sda1 /boot/efi                           512M vfat
├─sda2 /                                 461.4G ext4
└─sda3 [SWAP]                              3.9G swap
sdb                                      931.5G 
└─sdb1 /media/dee/128496546C7DF0E8       931.5G ntfs
sr0                                       1024M 
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   496GB  495GB   ext4
 3      496GB   500GB  4182MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Seagate BUP Slim SL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

It's working! In boot up I went to the recovery mode, I didn't really know what I was doing but updated grub and clean disk and when I rebooted it worked! Weird... anyway, thanks everyone. If anyone can offer any explanation of this, be interested to hear it.